# PayPal android integration infinite loading on payment

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to implement paypal payment, using their documentation on sandbox accounts. So, my code looks like this:

```
fun setupPayPal(
        payPalButton: PayPalButton, bottomSheetDialog: BottomSheetDialog,
        orderRequest: OrderRequest
    ) {
        val config = CheckoutConfig(
            application = fragmentActivity.application,
            clientId = Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
            environment = Environment.SANDBOX,
            returnUrl = "com.example.shopkotlin://paypalpay",
            currencyCode = CurrencyCode.USD,
            userAction = UserAction.PAY_NOW,
            settingsConfig = SettingsConfig(
            loggingEnabled = true
        ))

        PayPalCheckout.setConfig(config)

        payPalButton.setup(
            createOrder =
            CreateOrder { createOrderActions ->
                val order =
                    Order(
                        intent = OrderIntent.CAPTURE,
                        appContext = AppContext(userAction = UserAction.PAY_NOW),
                        purchaseUnitList =
                        listOf(
                            PurchaseUnit(
                                amount =
                                Amount(currencyCode = CurrencyCode.USD, value = "10.00")
                            )
                        ),
                        processingInstruction = ProcessingInstruction.ORDER_COMPLETE_ON_PAYMENT_APPROVAL
                    )
                createOrderActions.create(order)
            },
            onApprove =
            OnApprove { approval ->
                approval.orderActions.capture {
                    orderRequest.paymentMethod = "PayPal"
                    orderViewModel!!.createOrder(token, orderRequest)
                    bottomSheetDialog.cancel()
                }
            },
            onError = OnError { errorInfo ->
                println("error $errorInfo")
            }
        )
    }
```

The problem is that it's starts properly, i am logging in, however it stucks and infinite loading at sandbox.paypal.com , i am using Kotlin, on my Java application the same code works as charm, but this one does not, does someone knows why? I looked into logs, no error so far.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the return URL correctly. In `paypal.developer` we should set the URL how it is in my code, however we must make sure that URL matches, check in `build.gradle` (module).